# Is it possible to build a generic conversion for integer arrays in swift 2.2?

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

I have not been able to progress past the point illustrated below.

I am getting:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Element' to expected argument type 'IntegerLiteralType' (aka 'Int')
```

on the line where I am moving data from 'Element' to 'T'.  Also, I have not yet figured out how to extended truncating to UInt.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

```
protocol Truncating {
    init(truncatingBitPattern: IntegerLiteralType)
}

extension Int {
    init(truncatingBitPattern value: Int) { self.init(truncatingBitPattern: value.toIntMax()) }
}

protocol Bitshiftable {
    func <<(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func >>(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func <<=(inout lhs: Self, rhs: Self)
    func >>=(inout lhs: Self, rhs: Self)
}

protocol ArrayConvertable: IntegerType, Bitshiftable, Truncating {}

extension Int    : ArrayConvertable {}
extension Int8   : ArrayConvertable {}
extension Int16  : ArrayConvertable {}
extension Int32  : ArrayConvertable {}
extension Int64  : ArrayConvertable {}
//extension UInt   : ArrayConvertable {}
extension UInt8  : ArrayConvertable {}
extension UInt16 : ArrayConvertable {}
extension UInt32 : ArrayConvertable {}
extension UInt64 : ArrayConvertable {}

extension Array where Element: ArrayConvertable {
    func toInt<T: ArrayConvertable>() -> T?
    {
        let targetSize = sizeof(T)
        let sourceSize = sizeof(Element)
        let sourceByteCount = count * sourceSize
        guard targetSize == sourceByteCount else { return nil }

        var n: T = 0
        for e in self {
            var dataChunk = e
            for i in 0..<sourceSize {
                n = n | T(truncatingBitPattern: dataChunk)
                if i + 1 < sourceSize {
                    n = n << 8
                    dataChunk = dataChunk >> 8
                }
            }
        }

        return n
    }
}

func test() {
    let a8:  [UInt8]  = [0xab, 0xba, 0xda, 0xba, 0xd0, 0xd1, 0xd2, 0xd3, 0xfe, 0xdc, 0xba, 0x98, 0x76, 0x54, 0x32, 0x10]
    let a16: [UInt16] = [0xabba, 0xdaba, 0xd0d1, 0xd2d3, 0xfedc, 0xba98, 0x7654, 0x3210]
    let a32: [UInt32] = [0xabbadaba, 0xd0d1d2d3, 0xfedcba98, 0x76543210]
    let a64: [UInt64] = [0xabbadabad0d1d2d3, 0xfedcba9876543210]

    var n8:  UInt8  = 0
    var n16: UInt16 = 0
    var n32: UInt32 = 0
    var n64: UInt64 = 0

    print("--- 08 bit source")
    n8  = a8.toInt()!
    n16 = a8.toInt()!
    n32 = a8.toInt()!
    n64 = a8.toInt()!
    print(n8, n16, n32, n64)

    print("--- 16 bit source")
    n8  = a16.toInt()!
    n16 = a16.toInt()!
    n32 = a16.toInt()!
    n64 = a16.toInt()!
    print(n8, n16, n32, n64)

    print("--- 32 bit source")
    n8  = a32.toInt()!
    n16 = a32.toInt()!
    n32 = a32.toInt()!
    n64 = a32.toInt()!
    print(n8, n16, n32, n64)

    print("--- 64 bit source")
    n8  = a64.toInt()!
    n16 = a64.toInt()!
    n32 = a64.toInt()!
    n64 = a64.toInt()!
    print(n8, n16, n32, n64)
}

test()
```

Comment: Regardless of the implementation: Your assertion `targetSize == sourceByteCount` would always fail in the examples because the input arrays are too large for a single 8/16/32/64-bit integer. Or should the result be an *array* of the target type?

Comment: What would the expected result be if the input is `let a32: [UInt32] = [0x01020304, 0x05060708, 0x090a0b0c, 0x0d0e0f10]`, and the target type is `UInt16` ? And for target type `UInt64` ?

Comment: @MartinR There are some bugs in the body, but targetSize == sourceByteCount if, for example, target was UInt16 and source was [UInt8].count == 2.  The result of this function is always one of the integers.

Comment: @MartinR The result form your example would ideally be 0x0304.

Comment: One possible direction that I am looking at is to generalize truncatingBitPattern across all the integers.

Comment: Also, if we could get something like : n = { (sourceArrayPointer: UnsafePointer<Element>) in
    return unsafeBitCast(sourceArrayPointer, UnsafePointer<T>.self).memory
   }...to move data from Element to T, then that is another possible way to go.

Comment: And what should be the result for a conversion to UTF-64? I am asking because it is not completely clear to me how the byte-order should be handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is s possible solution which just re-interprets the data.
No protocol is needed:

```
extension Array where Element: IntegerType {
    func toInt<T: IntegerType>() -> T? {
        guard sizeof(T) <= count * sizeof(Element) else { return nil }
        return UnsafePointer<T>(self).memory
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let a32: [UInt32] = [0x11223344, 0x55667788, 0x99AABBCC, 0xDDEEFF00]
if let u16: UInt16 = a32.toInt() {
    print(String(format:"%#04x", u16)) // 0x3344
}
```

Comment: This is a really elegant.  One potential pitfall is that an Array is not guaranteed to be contiguous, which is not a problem for your example, but might be when going from [UInt8] to UInt64 as an example.

Comment: @SeanVikoren: I am fairly sure that passing an array to a function which takes a pointer (as in `UnsafePointer<T>(self)`) passes the address of the elements *contiguous storage.*